# Sharing GIS data with non-GIS users

Tags: qgis, software-recommendations, visualisation, qgis2web

I want to visualize and share GIS data with non-GIS users within my organization. The data basis is European CO2 emissions from industrial sites from the E-PRTR, thus a point data layer that should be visualized on a basemap. I am able to visualize the points differentiated by colors representing the different emission sectors and size proportional to the annual emissions via rule-based symbology in QGIS.

The non-GIS users should be able to move the map, zoom in and out and click on the points to be able to view the underlying data.

What options are available to share the data and the outlined visualization with non-GIS users?

I came across the plugin qgis2web, but I am facing several restrictions regarding a clear and good looking visualtization.

Is there another option I do not know about?

Comment: If you want a web-based map that can't be done with qgis2web then you'll have to make it from something like leaflet or openlayers. If you could detail your attempts with qgis2web and the problems then we might be able to get round them, but for now this is not a clear question.

Comment: You could run a QGIS server and share the content as WMS.

Comment: By "non-GIS users do you mean those who normally don't run/know GIS software or those who aren't allowed at work to install/use GIS software?  I ask because you could use the QPackage or QFieldSync plugins to create a self contained project which they could open and use in the simple fashion you mention with very little training.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Python knowledge. The Folium package is very good at creating pretty maps in a html format that can be shared through email or a file share. If you have Sharepoint, you can embed the html document on the Sharepoint page.

Here is code to get you started, assuming you have the data stored as a GeoJSON.

```py
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from folium import plugins
from folium.plugins import HeatMap, MarkerCluster, Search
import folium
import webbrowser
import pandas as pd

 m = folium.Map(location = [0, 0], zoom_start = 6, max_zoom = 20) #Centered at 0,0, change to your area
point = folium.GeoJson(r'Path to your json',
                    control = False,
                    marker = folium.CircleMarker(radius = 3, # Radius in metres
                                           weight = 0, #outline weight
                                           fill_color = '#ff0000 ' #change to hexidecimal color you want (this is red)
                                           line_color = '#ff0000 ',
                                           fill_opacity = 1),

                    ).add_to(m)

 m.save (r'PathToOutput.html')
 m.save (r'PathToOutput.aspx') #To create a file to share on Sharepoint
```

Here are some additional resources to see what you can do:

https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/visualization-of-air-pollution-using-folium-31258ad49f00
https://www.kaggle.com/code/tatianasnwrt/visualizing-air-quality-in-budapest-folium/notebook
https://towardsdatascience.com/visualizing-air-pollution-with-folium-maps-4ce1a1880677